# Move imageview from scrollview to relativelayout

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, android-relativelayout

How to move imageview from ScrollView to RelativeLayout using drag`n`drop (or else)?
Android 2.2/2.3.3+
I Need OnTouch take imageview and smooth move to relativeLayout...
Sorry for my English..

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if it is this you want but u could simply go to XML (no graphical layout with drag n drop), cut the ImagaView code and place it outside the ScrollView layout,

Just remember ScrollView can father only one object so u can create a LinearLayout around your image

FROM THIS

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView1">  


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="352dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/buttongod" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

TO THIS

```
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView1"  


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="352dp" >


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/buttongod" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: no.. the user must do this... like this: http://s019.radikal.ru/i601/1203/d0/27823f090029.jpg